# React - how to change the background color of an imported component?

Tags: json, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have three components (Box_1, Box_2, Box_3). For Box_1, I assigned the background color to orange. Then I imported the Box_1 component in other components. I want to know how to change the background color of Box_1 to green in the Box_2 component and in the Box_3 component add "display: flex" here is my example
https://codesandbox.io/live/wkt46tw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final Output:

[image]

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Box_1 } from "./components/box_1/1";
import { Box_2 } from "./components/box_2/2";
import { Box_3 } from "./components/box_3/3";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Box_1 style={{ backgroundColor: "green" }} />
      <Box_2 />
      <Box_3 style={{ flex: 1 }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

1.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

export class Box_1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div style={this.props.style} className="box_1">
          <p>Box_1</p>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

2.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Box_1 } from "../box_1/1";
import "./style.css";

export class Box_2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Box_1 style={this.props.style}/>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

3.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Box_1 } from "../box_1/1";
import "./style.css";

export class Box_3 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Box_1 style={this.props.style} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-brook-91uiu?file=/src/App.js)

also, read this article about naming conventions in react js.

[Naming Conventions](https://airbnb.io/javascript/react/)